# Neovim: How to stop lspconfig with html lsp from wrapping tags?

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin, nvim-lspconfig

I'm using Neovim together with lspconfig. I've setup the html lsp through Mason.
I'm pretty happy with it, though it keeps wrapping my tags even though I don't want it.

Is there any way I can change it (maybe by adjusting some lsp setting)?

I tried to disable wrap by

- `:set nowrap`
- `:set wrap!`
- `:set formatoptions-=t`
- `:set textwidth=0`
- `:set wrapmargin=0`

though none of these worked.

If I turn off HTML lsp it works as expected...